# Should upcoming computer scientists be worried about the rising competition in the field?

Tags: education

I am a high school student who is very interested in computer science and has been studying it since middle school. I've heard a lot of news about the rise in computer science majors in college and how that affects school acceptance rates.  Should I be worried about this and how it'll affect my college application experience or is it not a big deal? If I should be worried about this, how do I separate myself from others and raise my odds of being picked?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maximize your chances of admission, I suggest that you:

- Take the maximum number of computer science classes that you can.
- Take the maximum number of math classes you can.  Take the most advanced math classes you can.  For instance, if you have a chance to take AP calculus, do that.

Obviously, get as good grades in these classes as possible.

It's possible that it might also help to take as many science classes as possible (e.g., physics, etc).

And, of course, follow all the standard advice for how to do well in high school and maximize your chances for admission into college.

Important caveat: Admissions criteria vary by school, and generally are not public, so it's hard to know for sure what is best to do to raise your odds of admissions.